# Why is ZeroMQ poller not receiving messages (python)?

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, polling, pyzmq

I'm trying to use the ZeroMQ `Poller()` functionality with two sockets in python:

```py
import zmq

# Prepare our context and sockets
context = zmq.Context()

receiver = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
receiver.connect("ipc:///tmp/interface-transducer")

subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
subscriber.bind("ipc:///tmp/fast-service")
subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"10001")

# Initialize poll set
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(receiver, zmq.POLLIN)
poller.register(subscriber, zmq.POLLIN)

# Process messages from both sockets
while True:
    try:
        socks = dict(poller.poll())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

    if receiver in socks:
        message = receiver.recv()
        print("RECEIVER OK\n")

    if subscriber in socks:
        message = subscriber.recv()
        print("SUBSCRIBER OK\n")
```

And then the server that sends messages as a `ROUTER` is described as:

```py
def main():
    context = zmq.Context()
    router = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    router.bind("ipc:///tmp/interface-transducer")
    while True:
        identity = b'electrode-service'
        b_identity = identity
        router.send_multipart([b_identity, b'[1,2]'])
        print("Sent")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But when I run these two processes, it does not work as expected, the poller-script does not print anything. What could be the problem of such implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q** : *"What could be the problem of such implementation?"*

- such implementation is prone to deadlock & fails due to using exclusively the blocking-forms of `.poll()` & `.recv()` methods
- such implementation is not self-defending enough in cases, where multiple peers get connected into AccessPoints, that implement round-robin incoming/outgoing traffic mappings
- such implementation is awfully wrong in standing self-blinded in calling just a single `.recv()` in cases, where the `.send_multipart()` is strikingly warning, there will be multi-part message-handling needed
- `ipc://` Transport Class is prone to hide O/S related user-level code restrictions ( placed by the operating system on the format and length of a pathname and effective user-rights to R/W/X there )
- `ipc://` Transport Class `.connect()`-method's use is order-dependent for cases the target-address has not yet been created by O/S services ( a successful `.bind()` needs to happen first )
- last but not least, any next attempt to `.bind()` onto the same `ipc://` Transport Class target will silently destroy your intended `ROUTER`-access to the messaging/signalling-plane infrastructure & your implementation has spent zero-efforts to self-protect and self-diagnose errors that might silently appear "behind the curtains"

> Shouldn't zeromq deal automatically with deadlocks? I tried using the example given in the zeromq guide mspoller If I can't use .poll() and recv() simultaneously, how should I use ZMQ Poller structure? – hao123

**No**,
ZeroMQ zen-of-zero is performance + low-latency focused, so kindly consider all due care for blocking-prevention to be in your own hands (as needed & where needed, the core lib will never do a single more step than needed for the goal of achieving an almost linear scalable performance ).

**No,**
 use freely both `.poll()`- & `.recv()`-methods, yet complete it so as to fit into a non-blocking fashion - **`.poll( 0 )`** & add active detection + handling of multi-part messages ( again, best in a non-blocking fashion, using `zmq.NOBLOCK` option flag where appropriate ). Self-blocking gets code out of control.

Comment: Shouldn't zeromq deal automatically with deadlocks? I tried using the example given in the zeromq guide [mspoller](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/)
If I can't use `.poll()` and `recv()` simultaneosly, how should I use ZMQ Poller structure?

Comment: No, ZeroMQ zen-of-zero is performance + low-latency focused, so kindly consider all due care for blocking-prevention to be in your own hands (as needed & where needed, the core lib will never do a single more step than needed for the goal of achieving an almost linear scalable performance ). No, use freely both .poll() & .recv()-methods, yet complete it so as to fit into a non-blocking fashion - .poll( 0 ) & add active detection + handling of multi-part messages ( again, best in a non-blocking fashion, using zmq.NOBLOCK option flag where appropriate ). Self-blocking gets code out of control...

Comment: Please don't use an answer for Meta commentary. If you have any issues with how the community dealt with your answer, please post them on [Meta.SO](//meta.stackoverflow.com). Thanks.